Remov3e 301 redirect?
I want to remove 301 redirect from old url to new url.
I want old url give 404 error instead of redirecting to new url. I check all the possible factors in Rankmath like .htaccess file, robots.txt file and sitemap. i didn't found any redirection rule there. Even i submitted my url to Google search console and it shows temporarily removed url. but it still redirects.
/product/half-size-anaerobic-compost-bag/ (old url) --> which redirects to the new url -->/product/advance-jivamrut-liquid-composting-bag/
Please give me solution that works.
